Some details about relationship between central charges and second cohomology group of the Lie algebra
S. Weinberg in his book "The quantum theory of fields" talks about central charge that appear in Lie algebra of a given Lie group. To be more precise, on page 83 in the book, he computes the commutation relation of the Lie algebra as $[t_a ,t_b]=iC^a_{bc}t_a +iC_{bc}1$ where $1$ is called central charge and he says the appearance of terms on the right-hand side of the commutation relation proportional to the unit element (central charge) is the counterpart for the Lie algebra of the presence of phases in a projective representation of the group.
He then states a theorem as follows: the phase of any representation pf a given group can be removed if (a) the generators of the group in this representation can be reduced so as to eliminate all central charges from the Lie algebra. (b) Th group is simlply connected.
I think this the Bargmann theorem that says: If $G$ is a connected Lie group with $\pi_1 (G)=1$ and $H^2 (\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{R})=0$ (where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$), then every projective representation converts to a linear representation.
My question is that: What is the relation between central charges and second cohomology group of Lie algebra? If the generators of the group in the representation can be reduced so as to eliminate all central charges from the Lie algebra, then it means $H^2 (\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{R})=0$ and vice versa?
